# Write json to text file, jettison

Tags: java, jettison

I have created a JSONOBject `JSONObject features = new JSONObject();` which I want to store it in a txt file. I am using Jettison LIbrary for handling json files. However I didn't find a way to write json to file. Any idea?

Comment: Just write its `.toString()`

Comment: Yeah too easy not to notice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here; even org.json's `JSONObject` has a sane .toString() representation and it is probably the worst library you can use for JSON. Do you mean that jettison doesn't even do this right?

Comment: No it does it right, but I didnt notice .toString() solution.

Comment: Also, you can pass a param to the toString() method to pretty print (indent) the output, such as:  myJson.toString(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Json Writer](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFAQFjAD&url=http://www.json.org/java/org/json/JSONWriter.java&ei=gN9pU5OXFMaOrgeP44CABw&usg=AFQjCNGtaaVSz4V5PF4-EawuCWwgQIOw8g&sig2=Ym_jAteAK-VyDaSqguxEng&bvm=bv.66111022,d.c2E&cad=rja) to create a text which can be stored in a file.
The text generated here abides all of the syntax rules of JSON and allows you to save the JSON object as text file.